# Pagination for custom wp_query in wordpress page not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create pagination for website.com/blog, this page shows the latest post.
I create custom wp_query to show that but my default pagination won't work with this wp_query.
my wp_query is :

```
<?php
        $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $ck_posts = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' =>  2,
            'paged' => $paged
        ));
        if ($ck_posts->have_posts()) : while ($ck_posts->have_posts()) : $ck_posts->the_post();
                get_template_part('includes/e', 'post-card');
            endwhile;
            pagination();
        else : endif;
        ?>
```

and my default pagination is work fine in normal page but in custom wp_query have trouble,

pagination function code:

```
function pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if ($wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1) return;
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
    $max = intval($wp_query->max_num_pages);
    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ($paged >= 1) $links[] = $paged;
    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ($paged >= 3) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if (($paged + 2) <= $max) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";
    /** Previous Post Link */
    if (get_previous_posts_link()) printf('<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link());
    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if (!in_array(1, $links)) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf('<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url(get_pagenum_link(1)), '1');
        if (!in_array(2, $links)) echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort($links);
    foreach ((array)$links as $link) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf('<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url(get_pagenum_link($link)), $link);
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if (!in_array($max, $links)) {
        if (!in_array($max - 1, $links)) echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf('<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max)), $max);
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if (get_next_posts_link()) printf('<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link());
    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
}
```

what's wrong ? how can i fix this or create new function for this query like normal pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the global    `$wp_query`     does not contain the results of the custom query.

There may well be a good reason why this isn't a good idea but I don't know what it is, so my suggestion is to overwrite the global    `$wp_query`    before calling     `pagination()`

```
...
if ($ck_posts->have_posts()) : while ($ck_posts->have_posts()) : $ck_posts->the_post();
                get_template_part('includes/e', 'post-card');
            endwhile;
            $GLOBALS['wp_query']= $ck_posts;
            pagination();
        else : endif;
?>
```

For the current version of Wordpress (5.5.1), this is also why the inbuilt `the_pagination()` function doesn't work properly with custom queries. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/